# WPF - WP8: how to hide button visiblity?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

i have textbox with button. my deire is, if textbox is empty, the button should be deactivated (means 0.5 opacity). if user enters something in the textbox, the button should be set to visible. like if users clicked the button, again it should be deactivated unless it done the work for what purpose it has been clicked ?

Any ideas, how to do that ?

My CODE;

```
<Button Content="Go !" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="283,-3,0,0" Width="161" Name="searchbutton" Click="search" Height="78" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: Have you checked [TextBox.TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a value converter to convert the text of the TextBox to the Opacity value of the button:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBox" />
<Button Opacity="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtBox, Converter={StaticResource textToOpacityConverter}}" Content="Go !" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="283,-3,0,0" Width="161" Name="searchbutton" Click="search" Height="78" BorderBrush="Transparent"  />
```

This is the value converter:

```
    public class TextToOpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string)) 
        {
            return 0.5;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you need more info about ValueConverter you can see here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/value-converter-in-wpf-part-i/

Comment: Of course you can do the same thing with the IsEnabled property of the button ;)

Answer (score 0):

This control Template can be used to set the opacity of button if Textbox text is empty.

```
       <ControlTemplate x:Key="myButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="100" x:Name="searchTxt" Text="{Binding}"></TextBox>
                <Button x:Name="myButton">Search</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="searchTxt" Property="Text" Value="">
                    <Setter TargetName="myButton" Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

control implementing the template

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource myButtonTemplate}">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like as said Emanuele use just IsEnable property will setcolor of button to grey :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextChanged` event and then use Length on the text inside it. For button just use `Click` event and set `Opacity` to your desired value.